# How to get the unique generalized inverse matrix that we need？

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

For matrix equation ***A***x = **b** (***A*** is a $3×4$ matrix, ***x*** is $4×1$ vector , **b** is $3×1$ vector).

now, we have matrix **A** , vector **b** and already know that the third value of ***x*** is zero. How can we get the vector ***x*** by using the generalized inverse matrix of ***A*** .

Comment: Why generalized inverse? If $A=[\tilde{A},a]$, where $\tilde{A}$ is square and $a$ is the last column of $A$ and $x=[\tilde{x}^T,0]^T$ is the conforming partitioning of $x$ with the last component zero, $Ax=b$ gives the relation $\tilde{A}\tilde{x}=b$ for the leading components of $x$.

Comment: The third value of x is zero , actually x is  the form x = [x1,x2,0,1]T

Comment: I see, I can't read. Anyway, if some components of $x$ are given, you just move them to the right-hand side and solve a system for the remaining components with smaller number of columns in the matrix.

Comment: Excellent advice, Thank you very much for help. I have tried your advice and the result is very good.@ Algebraic Pave.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $G_{4\times 3}$ is a generalized inverse of $A$.

than we know that, 
$$AGA=A$$
which means that 
for any $x$ 
$$AGAx=Ax$$
$$\implies AGb=b\quad(\because Ax=b)$$

which shows that $Gb=x$.

so, once you the generalized inverse of $A$ then $Gb$ will be the solution.

That $x=Gb$ is always a solution.

If you want a unique generalized inverse, Moore-Penrose inverse instead of generalized inverse will do the necessary.